# Laravel - Salvar imagem da div para arquivo?

Tags: laravel

Eu preciso montar um form (`blade`) onde colo uma imagem, utilizo `javascript` e funciona sem problemas, mas, quando tento recuperar essa imagem no `controller`, os dados não são passados.

No `HTML` estou utilizando `CANVAS`:

```
<canvas class="imagem" id='imagem' width="1200" height="400" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

No Javascript quando tento salvar:

```
<script>
    <!--
    function exportCanvas(form){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('imagem');
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

        alert(dataURL);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/imagem",
            data: { 
                imgBase64: dataURL
            }
        }).done(function(o) {
            console.log('saved'); 
            // Do here whatever you want.
        });

        //form.submit;
    }
    -->  
</script>
```

No meu `controller`:

```
$data = $request->imgBase64;
```

mas a variável `$data` apresenta valor *nulo*.

Comment: Como está o código de sua controller?

Comment: <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ImagemController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) {
        return view('imagem.imagem');
    } 

    public function edit(Request $request) {

        // $captura = $request->captura;
        $data = $request->imgBase64; 
        // $image = Image::make($request->get('imgBase64'));
        var_dump($data);
        
    } 
    return '';
}

Comment: O código no controller está bem simples, somente para eu verificar se os dados foram passados.

Comment: O que acontece quando você exibe o conteúdo da request? Exemplo: `var_dump($request->all());`

Comment: Quando executo um var_dump() o valor que apresenta na tela é null.

Comment: Estranho... Tente trocar o método `ajax` por `$.post('/imagem', { imgBase64: dataURL });`